# Why are there so many dependencies when using Roslyn Scripting API?

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I'm currently evaluating Roslyn Scripting and I follow the descriptions on this *Scripting API Samples* Wiki page:
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples

To start, I'm using VS2017 and create a simple WinForms project targeting .NET FW 4.6.1 and I install the Scripting API by adding the nuget package like so:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting
```

That's fine and the samples from the above page work nicely as well. However, what surprises me is that by installing that nuget package, a list of 47 other packages it depends on is detected and added to the packages.config file of my project. All those are added to the packages folder, which now has 279 MB in total! Amongst that packages are animals like "System.Console.4.3.0" or "System.Linq.4.3.0" which I guess are substitutions for the same or similar named assembles already contained in my .NET Framework installation.

So here are my two questions:

1. Why are there so many dependencies of assemblies already present on
   my computer?
2. Do I really need to use these versions? Can I just use the "standard" versions coming with .NET FW 4.6.x?

Thanks!

Comment: When you hit build, does all the dlls copied to `bin` folder ? I don't think all of them.
I'm using it in my project (.NET 4.6) and it only copies few dlls

Comment: 24 DLLs are landing in the bin folder. Obviously, many of them re-implement stuff that's already in .NET Framework. I guess this has to do with the .NET Standard or Core (?) approach. Perhaps someone can explain that or knows a link to a good article?

Comment: Here's a related discussion that might give you some insight to #1 but no solution as to #2: https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/6bf48q/nugetroslyn_dependencies_are_getting_ridiculous/